# How to write yaml code for Render with docket and github action?

Tags: github, deployment, cloud, github-actions, render

Can we write yaml code using docker and ci cd pipeline for machine learning model deployment,like we do in Heraku, if yes? what will be the main.yaml code??

...code for main.yaml for Render cloud...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.